# Adding custom objects to NSMutable array not working, addObject returns empty array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am making a number of custom objects. I want to add each object to an array, but after the code below is run the array is still empty.

```
for (int i = 0; i<= numberOfObjectsWanted; i++) {
     CustomClass *object = [[CustomClass alloc]init];
     [objectsArray addObject:object];
}
```

objectsArray is an NSMutableArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your array is `nil`, no message sends will have any effect on it...

```
objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding the object that was created.  Try...

```
for (int i = 0; i<= numberOfObjectsWanted; i++) {
     CustomClass *object = [[CustomClass alloc]init];
     [objectsArray addObject:object];
}
```

**EDIT** - The new code in the question looks better now.  The next thing to check is whether you have a good mutable array to begin with.  Try `NSLog(@"array is %@", objectsArray);`
inside the loop.

Comment: @Mrwolfy You sure the array is created properly and it's not `nil`?

Comment: Thanks so much danh. I accepted the other answer only because it's brevity might be more helpful for others.